# Image Magick Not Processing All Images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, grayscale

I'm currently trying to convert a batch of images to greyscale using:

convert "* .jpg" -set colorspace Gray -separate -average "*.jpg"

Right now I'm working on a couple of hundred images. When I run the command I get copies of all the images, but only the 1st is actually converted to greyscale. Anyone know how what the issue might be? Also, if anyone has a better way of working through a very large quantity of images (ultimately I'll need to convert several thousand) at a time I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to loop over the images, and do one at the time. You'll need to indicate what shell you're using, as that will affect proper syntax to write the loop.

Comment: In ImageMagick, you cannot have wild cards (*) for the output. Wildcards are permitted for the input. So you will either have to use a for loop over each file in a list or directory or use mogrify rather than convert. Mogrify will automatically loop over each file in a directory. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, you can not have wildcards as the output. If you want to overwrite the original files with the updated colorspace, you can try the `mogrify` utility.

```
mogrify -set colorspace Gray -separate -average *.jpg
```

But that can be risky as your destroying originals. A simple for-loop might be easy to schedule & manage.

```
for filename in $(ls *.jpg)
do
    convert "$filename" -set colorspace Gray -separate -average "output_${filename}"
done
```

> ultimately I'll need to convert several thousand

If you really are facing large quantities of tasks, I would suggest spreading the tasks over multiple CPU cores. Perhaps with GNU Parallel.

```
parallel convert {} -set colorspace Gray -separate -average output_{.} ::: *.jpg
```

Of course I'm assuming your working with BASH on a *nix system. YMMV elsewhere.

Comment: With mogrify, you can create a new directory ahead of time and then in the mogrify command, use -path to point the output images to the new directory. That way you do not risk overwriting the input.